# while getting locale value in java on window server always return en_US

Tags: java, servlets

I have changed my operating system language to French. When i have run java file on spring tool suite framework on my local machine then it return correct locale value.But when i create a war file and deploy it on server then it always return locale value as "en_US".

I have used java function as bellow :-

```
String locale = Locale.getDefault();
```

I have also used

```
system.getproperties("user.language");
```

but get the same result.

Comment: anyone have solution please heip me.

Comment: Anyone figure me out please........